# Intersect knockoutjs observablearray using linqjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I wrote a extender function to observableArray in knockout js. What I'm looking for is a way to extract the intersection records based on one property. This works well on smaller number of arrays, but shows pretty poor performance in larger arrays. I dont know if it is the observables that makes it slower?

How would you guys write it?

**obsArray2** - The array to compare with

**Key** - Name of the property to compare between

```
ko.observableArray.fn.intersect = function (obsArray2, Key) {
    var self = Enumerable.From(ko.unwrap(this));
    var arrValues1 = self.Select(function (item) { return ko.unwrap(item[Key]); });
    arrValues2 = Enumerable.From(ko.unwrap(obsArray2)).Select(function (item) { return ko.unwrap(item[Key]); });
    var IntersectedValues = arrValues1.Intersect(arrValues2).ToArray();

    return self.Where(function (item) { return IntersectedValues.contains(ko.unwrap(item[Key])) }).ToArray();
    return obsArray1.Intersect(obsArray2).ToArray();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use linq.js for anything time sensitive, it is known to be slow, definitely compared to just using old skool `for` loops and arrays. Which is what I would use.

Other than, if I were to write this, I would consider naming some thing differently:

- `obsArray2` -> `observableArray`, there is no `obsArray1`, and it was not clear at first if obs means there are objects in the array or it is an observable arrays.
- `self` -> anything but `self` which usually refers to `this`, perhaps `enum1` ?
- `arrValues1` really contains an `Enumerable` which is not really an array, confusing, I would perhaps have chosen `set1` because in maths, intersections are made of sets or `enum1` because that is what the variable type is
- Same for `arrValues2` of course
- `intersectedValues` -> I would have gone for simply `intersection`

Furthermore,

- You have 2 `return` statements, [there can be only one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_(franchise))
- It seems silly to go back to `self` and filter out only elements that are in the intersection, can't you build the return value from `intersectedValues` ?

Comment: Thank you. Naming variables is a skill i really lack. Thank you for great pointers!

What would you use linqjs for? Smaller tasks?

Comment: I would use linqjs for complex operations with little volume.